# Compile with recent gcc on RHEL6: How to distribute the software?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, redhat, software-distribution

My software compiles on a variety of OSes, including RHEL7. I have a request to build it to run on RHEL6. My problem is that my C++ code relies a lot on C++11 features that are not present in gcc-4.4, the one coming with RHEL6.

I've seen there are ways to have more recent gcc versions to run on RHEL6, such as the Developer ToolSet for instance. I've no doubt I'll be able to build my software for RHEL6.

However, once compiled with, say, gcc-6, what will I have to provide with the binaries of my software? The C library of gcc-6? The C++ library of gcc-6? Should I instead link them statically to my binary?

On top of that, for RHEL, my software is packaged into .rpm files, and installs at standard locations: /usr/bin, /usr/lib ... Where would I install these new C and C++ library files on the target system? (Obviously not in /usr/lib where they may interfere with the default ones!)

**Edit:** My software is a shared object, I guess I can statically link the C++ library? But what about the program (I've no control on it) that will use my shared object. Can it use another version of the C++ library? Won't the linker find lots of duplicates? Looks like I'd open a can of worms...

**Edit:** Would it be possible to use the more recent gcc compiler with the standard C++ library of the RHEL6 stock one?

Comment: I'm not an expert there, but I hear many people are happy with [Docker](https://www.docker.com/).

Answer (score 3):

You can distribute your application together with an appropriate dynamically-linked version of the standard C++ library. You don't have to place it in /usr/lib but you have to link your app in such a way that it finds the right version of the library (see -rpath parameter to the linker).

On top of that you need to make sure your app doesn't use newer features of glibc (or else ship an appropriate version of glibc together with the application too). The easiest way to ensure that is to build everything (the app and the newer gcc) against an older version of glibc. And the easiest version of doing *that* is to build on an older version of the OS (but with the new compiler).

Comment: I am not so familiar with Linux shared object models.  On Windows, there is definitely potential pain if an application uses one version of the runtime and a linked DLL uses another.  This is particularly a problem if one creates the object and another deletes it.  It depends on the interface of the DLL/so.

Comment: @MartinBonner on Linux only one version of the library is usually loaded, if the app manages to load the latest version it"s golden, as all libraries will use it. If you somehow manage to load two different versions you will definitely have problems (not potentially) but this normally doesn't happen.

Answer (score 1):

Statically linking your binary against the standard library is definitely the simplest solution.  Potential issues:

- You then become responsible for releasing a new version of your application when a vulnerability is found in one of the libraries (rather than your users being responsible for keeping the libraries on their system patched).
- This only really works if *everything* is linked together into a single binary.  If your application is currently packaged as a series of different shared objects, you don't really want to have the run-time library statically linked into each.

As [The Quantum Physicist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1317944/the-quantum-physicist) notes in a comment, container solutions such as [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) can also be a good (and easy to maintain) solution.

Solving the general problem of packaging a new version of the run time libraries with your application is a much more interesting question, and hopefully somebody will be along shortly to explain how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

FYI - WRT Developer Toolset, if you compile with it on RHEL 6, it will run on both RHEL 6 an 7.

Comment: Hi Mike. My  question relates to the user of my shared object compiled with Developer Toolset on RHEL 6: Will he/she have to install the Developer Toolset on his/her system to compile his/her program and run it, or will the stock gcc-4.4 be enough ?